# Why does rdkit's `AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts.RunReactants` return a tuple of tuples?

Tags: cheminformatics

In rdkit, the function `AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts.RunReactants` returns a tuple of tuples. Does anyone know what the two dimensions are for? From the (admittedly few) examples I've seen, the inner tuples are always just one molecule.

The docstring says,

```
RunReactants( (ChemicalReaction)arg1, (tuple)arg2) -> object :
apply the reaction to a sequence of reactant molecules and 
return the products as a tuple of tuples
```

example:

```
from rdkit import rdBase, Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem, Draw
rxn = AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts('[c:1][c:2][c:3]>>[c:1][c:2]([F])[c:3]')
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1ccccc1')
ps = rxn.RunReactants((m,))

((<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10be03818>,),
 (<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10bef92f0>,),
 (<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10bef9a28>,),
 (<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10bef99d0>,),
 (<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10bef9768>,),
 (<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10bef9920>,),
 (<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10bef96b8>,),
 (<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10bef98c8>,),
 (<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10bef95b0>,),
 (<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10bef9710>,),
 (<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10bef9558>,),
 (<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol at 0x10bef9ad8>,))
```

The reason I ask is that I want to put the products into a pandas dataframe (already accomplished) and label the columns and indices according to the intended scheme.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I know that rdkit is used extensively in cheminformatics, but this question is not about chemistry itself and not a question how to apply the specific software to a given problem. I would think this is off-topic for our site.

Comment: Thank you @Martin, I see your point. I've posted the question to rdkit-discuss@lists.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [a tutorial I wrote on SMARTS reactions in rdkit](https://github.com/tentrillion/rdkit-tutorials/blob/master/notebooks/003_SMARTS_ReactionsExamples.ipynb):

> The output is a tuple of tuples. The inner tuples are there because even reactions that take only a single input molecule can result in multiple output molecules (e.g. hydrolysis). The outer tuples are there because rdkit applies your reaction incidence of the appropriate motifs in the input molecule, even if it occurs more than once.

The examples in the tutorial illustrate both cases where a single application of the reaction rule creates multiple molecules (the inner tuple(s) would have length > 1), and also cases where a reaction rule can be applied more than once to a molecule, which would lead to the outer tuples having length > 1.

Comment: Thank you for answering, and thanks for the tutorial as well Curt!